# Minimum number of squares required in grid so that the next square added is not isolated

Tags: puzzle

Given a rectangular grid with $n$ rows and $m$ columns in which squares may be placed, what are minimum number of squares required so that the next square added cannot be placed in isolation?

Isolation is defined as not attached to a side of at least 1 another square. A square only attached to the corner of another square is still isolated.

Example:

[image]

I have developed a [spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6kjzn529zdjsjt/Andrews%20puzzle%20solved%20v1.1.xlsx?dl=0) to try and solve this but it does so in a sum-what convoluted way. I also keep finding problems with it. It needs adapting to work with all small grids (eg 1 by x shapes where x is 5 or greater, 2x5 and 3x6). You may or may not find it useful. [link to spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6kjzn529zdjsjt/Andrews%20puzzle%20solved%20v1.1.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Do squares with touching corners count as being _in isolation_ of one another?

Comment: Yes they are still isolated. I have developed a spreadsheet but it comes to an answer in a sum-what convoluted way. However I keep finding problems with it. It needs adapting to work with all small grids (eg 1 by x shapes where x is 5 or greater, 2x5 and 3x6). You may or may not find it useful. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6kjzn529zdjsjt/Andrews%20puzzle%20solved%20v1.1.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I suggest editing your question to clarify my question about touching corners. That way, potential answerers to this question won't have to read the comments to find the full details (and are thus more likely to answer). Additionally, adding those example images on the excel sheet you linked me to the body of your question will make it more attractive and easier to digest. This will increase the chance that your question is answered in a satisfying way.

Comment: Thanks @Myridium, I have made the changes you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for taking it on board. Your question is now well-posed and gets my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Since each square touches itself and up to four others, the number required cannot be less than $\frac{nm}{5}$ and this is in a handwaving sense a possible limit when $n$ and $m \to \infty$ .

The only problem is the the edges, as shown here, where the "existing squares" are red.  The problem might go away on a particular torus.

[image]

Comment: pressed enter too soon.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I agree that the problem is the edges and that on a torus you could get $nm/5$. To resolve this we need to work out how often the white and red squares can be merged. On grids where $n>4$ and $m>4$ we could just look at the corners. If the distance between the corner and the closest white square on the $n$ axis $+$ the distance between the corner and the closest square on the $m$ axis $<5$, assuming the corner is square is counted as $1$, then only one of the $1$ white squares needs to be used.

Comment: When the total is $4<total>8$  only $1$  white squares needs to be used when the closest red square is also moved. This is the logic I put into the spreadsheet, however it doesn't work consistently on smaller grids.